# Sci-fi story or book where there was a system for recognizing a person as an adult after passing some kind of exam

Tags: story-identification, books

It is a story or book (sci-fi) where there was a system for recognizing a person as an adult after passing some kind of exam.

There was a main character (like a teenager or a child), and he came to visit a friend's family, and it turned out that that same friend (child) had passed the exam a long time ago and had some kind of adult badge.

And it seems like this child who has passed is younger than main character, and is either a surgeon or something like that. If I'm not mistaken, he is 12 years old.

I read this in the 2000s, but have no idea when it was published.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Hi, thank you! I read this in 2000s, but I have no idea about a year of publishing, sorry. Also I don't remember anything about cover.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Could this be [The Pre-persons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pre-persons)? In this story you are not even considered **human** before passing a test.

Comment: @user108131, thank you, but this is not what I'm looking for :(